# how i can loop in web scrape with python?

Tags: python

I have a problem for do multi for all post :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = 'http://www.thecoci.me/swift'

response = get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')

print(soup.find_all('a', {'itemprop': 'url'})['href'])
print(soup.find_all('a', {'itemprop': 'url'})[0].get_text())
```

how i can use this code for all post on this url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply loop over the list returned by `soup.find_all`.

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', {'itemprop': 'url'}):
    print(link['href'])
```

prints out

```
/swift/arrays/
/swift/stringinterpolation/
/swift/oprators/
/swift/datatype/
/swift/variableandconstant/
/swift/howtoinstallxcode/
```